# Something is wrong with the vimtutor

Tags: vim

After installing Vim on my PC, I wanted to check the vim tutor that came with it. After running the vim tutor command, it opens the file but for some reason its looks like this:

[image: vimtutor]

Any ideas why is that, and how can I fix it?

I tried reinstalling Vim but its no help.

Comment: Not sure what "file" you're specifically talking about. My first hunch after looking is a character encoding issue. Vim tutor is expecting one encoding but getting another and therefore improperly displaying characters. Unicode is often used when you need to offer instructions in another language like Chinese, for example, which has non alpha-numerical characters. Is it able to open other files normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I got this. It tried to show the text in my native language which is not English. I fixed it by typing `en` after the `vimtutor` command so it opens the file in English.